# Removing duplicate records by date

Tags: mysql

I have a large number of duplicate records in a mysql table

```
created_at                  updated_at                      aircraft_id status  flight_id           dep_airport_id arr_airport_id
2023-05-15 11:43:47.913580  2023-05-15 11:43:47.913580      24315713    landed  172572              1348    414
2023-05-15 11:42:55.817783  2023-05-15 11:42:55.817783      24314391    live    172572              1348    414
2023-05-15 11:41:56.414881  2023-05-15 11:41:56.414881      24313936    live    172572              1348    414
2023-05-15 11:40:35.270370  2023-05-15 11:40:35.270370      24312784    live    172572              1348    414
2023-05-15 11:39:41.299083  2023-05-15 11:39:41.299083      24312345    live    172572              1348    414
2023-05-15 11:38:14.149154  2023-05-15 11:38:14.149154      24311593    live    172569              9107    9107
2023-05-15 11:44:44.786622  2023-05-15 11:44:44.786622      24317026    live    172566              2118    2539
2023-05-15 11:43:36.652445  2023-05-15 11:43:36.652445      24315362    live    172566              2118    2539
2023-05-15 11:42:44.044968  2023-05-15 11:42:44.044968      24314171    live    172566              2118    2539
2023-05-15 11:41:41.031133  2023-05-15 11:41:41.031133      24313674    live    172566              2118    2539
2023-05-15 11:40:39.038395  2023-05-15 11:40:39.038395      24312866    live    172566              2118    2539
2023-05-15 11:39:45.055547  2023-05-15 11:39:45.055547      24312417    live    172566              2118    2539
2023-05-15 11:38:38.813783  2023-05-15 11:38:38.813783      24311820    live    172566              2118    2539
2023-05-15 11:37:42.244022  2023-05-15 11:37:42.244022      24311316    live    172566              2118    2539
2023-05-15 11:44:42.331242  2023-05-15 11:44:42.331242      24316965    live    172561              10604   2088
2023-05-15 11:43:36.613927  2023-05-15 11:43:36.613927      24315359    live    172561              10604   2088
2023-05-15 11:42:41.788895  2023-05-15 11:42:41.788895      24314111    live    172561              10604   2088
2023-05-15 11:41:38.670270  2023-05-15 11:41:38.670270      24313632    live    172561              10604   2088
2023-05-15 11:40:36.817905  2023-05-15 11:40:36.817905      24312813    live    172561              10604   2088
2023-05-15 11:39:42.277782  2023-05-15 11:39:42.277782      24312366    live    172561              10604   2088
2023-05-15 11:38:36.029754  2023-05-15 11:38:36.029754      24311769    live    172561              10604   2088
```

I am looking to remove all duplicates (keeping only the latest by `created_at`) record where `date` (YYYY-MM-DD), `aircraft_id`, `dep_airport_id` and `arr_airport_id` match.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: keeping only the latest)- based on created_at or updated_at? Do you want to delete all but the latest from db or select only the latest in a query? There only 1 row in the sample where dep_airport_id and arr_airport_id match so I wouldn't say the sample is representative.

Comment: Common `DELETE .. WHERE EXISTS`.

Comment: Update your post with the expected output. Note that "*arr_airport_id*" you mention in your post doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @lemon I updated my question to reflect the correct naming of `arr_airport_id` and also to keep only the latest `created_at` record.

Comment: Good, make sure to update your post with the expected output as well: it'll help us with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()` to order your records by group then select only the recent ones using the condition `rn = 1` :

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by aircraft_id, dep_airport_id, arr_airport_id, DATE(created_at) order by created_at desc ) as rn
  from mytable
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```